# form submission to upload images - how to capture script errors

Tags: javascript, php, html

I've got an HTML form which at a basic level does is the following. It's designed to upload images by calling the script image_upload.php.

```
<form id="browse-images"  enctype="multipart/form-data" action="image/image_upload.php"  method="post">
   <input id="upload" name="upload" class="submit-button btn btn-success upload-btn" style="display: none; width: 6em; float: right" type="Submit" value="Upload"/>
</form>
```

I have error handling in the image_upload.php script that checks if the file type is allowable, and throws an exception and returns that error as a JSON string.

I'm at a loss as to how to capture the string when the script has been called in this manner?

Comment: 1st of all, how are you uploading without the input type file ? 2nd could you post image_upload.php script here with question

Comment: good point I missed adding that information, I'll amend it tonight. However the crux of the problem is that I don't know how to capture the feedback from the action="image/image_upload.php" when submitted in this way. Normally I would stick a click handler on the form and call the script by ajax maybe but for images I've been unable to do this. This is more a question relating to return value capture rather than image uploads.

Comment: normally it should be like this to get the file uploaded to a location in server. considering your input will be
 <input name="file" type="file" id="file" />

<?php
if($_REQUEST['upload']=='Upload'){
 $upload_location="upload/";
 $image =$_FILES["file"]["name"];
 move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["name"],$upload_location.date("d_m_h_i_s").$_FILES["file"]["name"]);
}
?>